# How to pass user data using OpenCV trackbar

Tags: c++, opencv, void-pointers, trackbar

Currently I have a number of sliders that are used to change image values. I am using the OpenCV track bar for the slider which has a callback to a different function for each of my sliders. I would like to have my sliders callback point to a single callback function and then use the user data to identify which track bar made the call.

[Here is the documentation for the track bar](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=cvtrackbar#int%20cvCreateTrackbar%28const%20char%2a%20trackbar_name,%20const%20char%2a%20window_name,%20int%2a%20value,%20int%20count,%20CvTrackbarCallback%20on_change%29)

I am unsure what values i should be passing to void*, and also how to then retrieve this value form my callback function Below is an example of my track bar which compiles.

```
int ref = 1;
createTrackbar("Name","Window",0, 1, myFunc, &ref);
```

In my callback function I try and retrieve the value of ref.

```
void myFunc(int value, void *userdata)
{
    int val = *((int*)&userdata);
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

I had issues trying to convert the pointer back to an int, this is a solution i found online which gives me val as the address of ref.

```
int val = *((int*)&userdata);
```

This seems a lot of hassle, as i then have to get the value back form the address at val. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `int val = *((int *)userdata)`?

Comment: That returns the value instead of the address yes. I just wanted to know if there is a better way to send user data than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simplier way. It's nessesary minimum for functionality you want.

Comment: If that is the case then i will keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a single variable which seems less hassle.

```cpp
void cb_func(..., void *userdata) {
    int val = *static_cast<int *>(userdata);
}
```

Call it with:

```
cv_function_takes_callback(..., cb_func, static_cast<void *>(&val));
```

---

C++11 way of passing multiple variables.

 You can pass references and even lambda functions.

```
type1 var1;
type2 var2;
auto lambda_no_capture = [](...) { ... };

typedef std::tuple<type1, const type2 &, decltype(lambda_no_capture)> tup_t;
tup_t tup(var1, var2, lambda_no_capture);

auto cb_func = [](..., void *userdata) -> void {
    tup_t &tup = *static_cast<tup_t *>(userdata);
    type1 var1 = std::get<0>(tup);
    decltype(auto) var2 = std::get<const type2 &>(tup); // requires c++14
    auto lambda_no_capture = std::get<2>(tup);
};

cv_function_takes_callback(..., cb_func, static_cast<void *>(&tup));
```

A few notes:

- You can use `auto var1 = std::get<0>(tup);` but being explicit is better.
- In case you are using `auto` with referenced variables, use `const auto &var2 = std::get<1>(tup);`.
  If you are not bound to C++11, `decltype(auto)` is what this is for.
- Passing lambda functions to the callback functions seems cool but it is no different from using functions at global scope since they **cannot have captured parameters**.